# Get fullname from Active Directory on C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a problem about getting user's firstname and surname (fullname) from Active Directory. The code is below.

No problem with runing the project on my local. I can take data whatever I want. After publishing the project to remote server, it don't allow me to get firstname and surname (fullname), it just allows to get domain name and username. How can I fix it?

```
private string GetNameSurname()
    {
        string[] retVal;
        //Pull the username out of the domain\user string.  
        retVal = Page.User.Identity.Name.Split(new string[] { @"\"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        DirectoryEntry userEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + retVal[0] + "/" + retVal[1]);
        string namesurname = (string)userEntry.Properties["fullname"].Value;
        //return retVal[1];
        //retVal[1] gives username. 
        //retVal[0] gives domain name
        return namesurname;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the code to test for the same user?

Are you testing against AD in dev, Windows local accounts have a Full Name field (optional) but in AD the fields are named differently. Also, are you talking to the same version of AD.

According to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there is no field called Full Name, only First Name and Surname and Display Name.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about credentials. Try to add an administrator username and password when conecting to active directory.

Comment: How can i add administrator username and password?

Comment: I think there is a DirectoryEntry constructor that allows a username and password